# Is Chartjs compatible with PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, chart.js

Is Chartjs compatible with PhoneGap? I did a quick test but was unable to make it work.

As far as I know I do get the canvas but nothing is drawn on it...

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap does not provide it's own browser runtime, but uses the available runtime instead. Depending on your platform, [Chart.js](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js) might not work flawlessly, but that has nothing to do with PhoneGap.

Also note that Chart.js has many unresolved bugs on GitHub (like [this one](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/273)) and has not seen any updates in months.

Comment: That particular bug seems to be fixed in a latest version